# I am trying to access 'Energy Indicator.xls'

Tags: python

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np   
x=pd.ExcelFile('Energy Indicator.xls')
energy= x.parse(skiprows =17, skip_footer=38))
 ...
```

I got the following error message:

```
FileNotFoundError, no such file or directory.
```

Comment: rename your xls to Energy_Indicator.xls

Comment: You need to give the path to an existing file. The error is telling you that `Energy Indicator.xls` does not exist in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to declare your filepath specification with something like `os.path` or `filedialog` from tkinter.